# Dataflow process hanging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-data-api

I am running a batch job on dataflow, querying from BigQuery. When I use the DirectRunner, everything works, and the results are written to a new BigQuery table. Things seem to break when I change to DataflowRunner.

The logs show that 30 worker instances are spun up successfully. The graph diagram in the web UI shows the job has started. The first 3 steps show "Running", the rest show "not started". None of the steps show any records transformed (i.e. outputcollections all show '-'). The logs show many messages that look like this, which may be the issue:

```
skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "python" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=python pod=......
```

I took a step back and just ran the minimal wordcount example, and that completed successfully. So all the necessary APIs seem to be enabled for Dataflow runner. I'm just trying to get a sense of what is causing my Dataflow job to hang.

I am executing the job like this:

```
python2.7 script.py --runner DataflowRunner --project projectname --requirements_file requirements.txt --staging_location gs://my-store/staging --temp_location gs://my-store/temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if my solution was the cause of the error pasted above, but fixing dependencies problems (which were not showing up as errors in the log at all!) did solve the hanging dataflow processes.

So if you have a hanging process, make sure your workers have all their necessary dependencies. You can provide them through the --requirements_file argument, or through a custom setup.py script.

Thanks to the help I received in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653847/nltk-dependencies-in-dataflow), the pipeline appears to be operating, albeit [VERY SLOWLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680416/dataflow-pipeline-slow).